# Synchronization in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, synchronization, parfor

I'm processing data in parallel using `parfor` in this way:

```
iteration = 10;
result = zeros(1, iteration);

matlabpool open local 2
    parfor i = 1:iteration
        data = generate_data();
        result(i) = process_data(data);
    end
end
matlabpool close
```

It works fine, but I have one problem. My function `generate_data` generates unique data (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ...) but in practice sometimes I give same value two times (and I give 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, ...). In simple my function looks like this:

```
function data = generate_data()

persistent counter generated_data;

if(isempty(counter))
    counter = 1;
    generated_data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]; 
end

data = generated_data(counter);
counter = counter + 1;
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this:

```
function data = generate_data(id)

persistent generated_data;
if(isempty(generated_data))
    generated_data = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]; 
end

data = generated_data(mod(id - 1, length(generated_data)) + 1);
```

In each call I can generate data set on demand using `id`. I have to remember that one data set can be reached only for one `id`. It works, but not solve my problem. I would eliminate parametr `id` and use internal counter like in first post.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you want to ensure that your `generate_data` doesn't return the same value to two iterations of your `PARFOR` loop. Unfortunately, you cannot do this directly in the `PARFOR` loop, since no communication is allowed. Your options are basically: either call `generate_data` on the MATLAB client; or run two `PARFOR` loops perhaps like this:

```
parfor ii = 1:iteration
  generated(ii) = generate_data();
end

% omit duplicated values - perhaps you might wish to generate
% some more here too...
generated = unique(generated);

parfor ii=1:numel(generated)
  result(ii) = process_data(generated(ii));
end
```

Comment: But I can't generate whole data set at once. This is example. In real I'm generating large sets of data. Ideally, the operations performed in generate_data were treated as a single atomic instruction.